# Concerns with NoSQL/MongoDB

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, jpa, nosql

I'm starting to build a new Spring-based multi-user document management application and I would like to venture into the world of NoSQL/MongoDB.  Coming from a RDBMS background, I have several concerns with MongoDB, primarily:

1. Lack of transactions
2. More focused on performance/scalability than data integrity
3. Lack of a JPA standard

To start with, I do not expect high loads or massive reads vs writes.  I suspect reads to writes will be about 10 to 1.  Additionally, I do not expect very high loads - especially to start.

1) From what I can tell, there is no easy way to do multi-collection transactions.  Where in a RDBMS I can easily have a per-user document ID counter maintained in a separate table, there does not seem to be a way to do this reliably in MongoDB given that it would be in a separate collection/document.  Consequently, I'm not sure if/how one resolves this problem.

2) Additionally, from what I have read, NoSQL is great where data integrity isn't the primary concern (ex: blog comments, etc).  However, I'm not sure how this translates to being the primary data store for an application.  Does this mean that one can update a document and have it fail?  I ran across an [older unaccredited rant](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FD3xe6Jt) which discusses failed commits/etc which further flames the concerns.

3) The seemingly lack of a JPA-like standard for NoSQL would imply that I have to choose my DB and stick with it.  Unlike JPA where I can easily swap one DB vendor for another JPQ/SQL compliant vendor, I have to code with MongoDB in mind and redesign my structure/queries if ever I wanted to switch to another NoSQL DB.  I've seen Hibernate OGM, but it seems that it is still very much in its infancy and only provides rudimentary support.  Definitely not something that would avoid mongodb specific queries.

Are these concerns easily mitigated?  Being new to the NoSQL world, I'm still having trouble understanding the right business case when to use NoSQL.

Comment: At the cost of advocating for the devil, why use NoSQL? Shouldn't you be choosing the tool for your requirement rather than choosing the tool and then wondering 'how do I use this to nail this nail?' (unless of course you are trying to learn the tech). If your data makes more sense with relations, has a fixed schema, not much volume and has no qualms with ACID constraints, why look for something else?

Comment: @prabugp For starters, am trying to learn the tech. :)  Secondly, not fully knowing the tech, it is hard for me to know if a NoSQL db makes sense in this instance.  There are a lot of cases where I can see the schemaless-structure making the design easier.  However, these transaction/ACID issues make me wonder how truly effective it would be more my needs.  I suspect others have already encountered these issues, so am looking for feedback if I misunderstand the NoSQL/MongoDB constraints, or if solutions exist, or if this is just something that I would need to live with.

Comment: DataNucleus JPA has supported MongoDB since a long time ago, but then JPA is designed explicitly for RDBMS, so JPQL does not "fit" other types of datastores, JDO and JDOQL OTOH does.

Comment: Check out Oracle NoSQL, which can be tuned to support data integrity. Also, NoSQL database should not be use as your primary datasource.

Comment: NoSQL != Just MongoDB.  Neo4j supports transactions iirc.

Comment: @hubertboateng Can you elaborate please?  Why should NoSQL not be a primary datasource?

Answer (score 0):

These are good questions. Here's my 2 cents about MongoDB and some references to help you learn more. I won't speak about any other NoSQL thingies as there are a lot out there and there's no real unifying principle to NoSQL other than "it doesn't use SQL", except sometimes people make it work with SQL, so, yeah.

1. MongoDB does not do joins. Period. MongoDB does not have transactions - whether within one collection or involving multiple collections. The unit of atomicity is the document. How does this work in an application? Via [schema design](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)and some techniques for recovering parts of ACID semantics if necessary, for example using [two-phase commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). In relational databases, schema design is straightforward and is based on the structure of the data and not its use case. Joins and transactions fill in the gap between the abstract, normalized data representation and the concrete ways the data will be used. The data modeling intro already linked explains the situation for MongoDB, for contrast:

   > The key challenge in data modeling is balancing the needs of the application, the performance characteristics of the database engine, and the data retrieval patterns. When designing data models, always consider the application usage of the data (i.e. queries, updates, and processing of the data) as well as the inherent structure of the data itself.
2. That specific "rant" is clearly very old as it talks about writes being unacknowledged by default. [This isn't the case anymore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/). Given any distributed computer system operating over a network, it's pretty easy to come up with a way for it to behave poorly . The MongoDB blog covered a lot of this stuff in a [series on consistency](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/475279604/on-distributed-consistency-part-1). I'd suggest touring the docs about journaling, replication, and write concern and see if that makes you feel better about MongoDB as a primary data store.
3. Yup. This comes with the NoSQL territory. What doesn't exist is common data access languages or standards because everything is new and trying to be different. Check back in 30 years.